# FloatingPointError only shows up in a specific program

Tags: python, numpy, underflow

I have the same piece of code written in two programs. However I only get the error while running it one program.

Here is the file that is works with:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

#FileName: test.py
import numpy as np
import math
mu = 0
sigma = 3

x_at_mean = math.pow(math.e, -(math.pow(mu, 2) / 2*math.pow(sigma,2))) / (sigma*math.sqrt(2*math.pi))
alpha = lambda index_array, i,j: ((((np.e**(-((np.sqrt((index_array[0]- i)**2 + (index_array[1]-j)**2) - mu)**2)/(2*sigma**2)))/(sigma*np.sqrt(2*np.pi)))*150) / x_at_mean)
xyz = np.indices((450,450))

print alpha(xyz, 35,35)
```

Now here is the function from a different file using the exact same code:

```
def gfx_create_fake_tem2(self, *args):
    mu = 0
    sigma = 3

    x_at_mean = math.pow(math.e, -(math.pow(mu, 2) / 2*math.pow(sigma,2))) / (sigma*math.sqrt(2*math.pi))
    alpha = lambda index_array, i,j: ((((np.e**(-((np.sqrt((index_array[0]- i)**2 + (index_array[1]-j)**2) - mu)**2)/(2*sigma**2)))/(sigma*np.sqrt(2*np.pi)))*150) / x_at_mean)        
    xyz = np.indices((450,450))  
    print alpha(xyz, 35, 35)
```

This is the error I get when i try to call the function:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/ian/python/tsase/xyz/xyz2.py", line 127, in <lambda>
  self.draw_tem.connect("clicked", lambda w: self.event_changeTem())
File "/home/ian/python/tsase/xyz/xyz2.py", line 495, in event_changeTem
  self.gfx_render()
File "/home/ian/python/tsase/xyz/xyz2.py", line 610, in gfx_render
  self.gfx_create_fake_tem2()
File "/home/ian/python/tsase/xyz/xyz2.py", line 921, in gfx_create_fake_tem2
  ie.gfx_create_fake_tem2()
File "/home/ian/python/tsase/xyz/imageEval.py", line 249, in gfx_create_fake_tem2
  print alpha(xyz, 35,35)
File "/home/ian/python/tsase/xyz/imageEval.py", line 247, in <lambda>
  alpha = lambda index_array, i,j: ((((np.e**(-((np.sqrt((index_array[0]- i)**2 + (index_array[1]-j)**2) - mu)**2)/(2*sigma**2)))/(sigma*np.sqrt(2*np.pi)))*150) / x_at_mean)
FloatingPointError: underflow encountered in divide
```

I do not understand what could cause it to run correctly in one instance and error out in another. I am not passing any variables in or out and I am not using any global variables.

Does anyone know what could cause this?

Comment: Are you running both on the same platform with the same version of python?

Comment: Yes I am. It is python 2.7.3, if that matters.

Comment: I was hoping it would just be 64 v 32 bit issue. I don't have a clue outside of that.

Comment: I can't reproduce it on my system... Anything weird about the class the function is a member of?

Comment: I use the class for GUI stuff, so the class takes a GTK.Window. I am not sure if that is considered weird, but it is all I can think of.

Comment: Perhaps the numpy settings are different per program? http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/misc.html#how-numpy-handles-numerical-exceptions

Comment: Hey Ben, you pointed me in exactly the right direction. Turns out my smaller test program had the errors set to ignore and that is why it was not giving me errors. I am not sure why numpy choose to set how errors are handled differently, before you pointed me here I had not used seterr() on either of my files.